# perl :"//" operator?

Tags: perl

I have a question about using "//" operator, my testing code is as following:

```
perl -e '@arr1=();@arr2=(1,2,3);@arr3=defined(@arr1)?@arr1:@arr2;print "[@arr3]\n"' 

[1 2 3] 

perl -e '@arr1=();@arr2=(1,2,3);@arr3=@arr1//@arr2;print "[@arr3]\n"' 

[0] 

perl -e '$v1=();$v2="123";$v3=defined($v1)?$v1:$v2;print "[$v3]\n"' 

[123] 

perl -e '$v1=();$v2="123";$v3=$v1//$v2;print "[$v3]\n"' 

[123]
```

my question is, why do using "//" operator give the same results as using "defined()? : " on the scalar, but not array(or hash)?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 20):

Because the leftmost operand of `?:`, `||`,  or `&&` — or this newfanglulated `//` thingie — is always evaluated in boolean not list context, whereas the other operands inherit the surrounding context.

```
@a = @b && @c;
```

means

```
if (@b) {
     @a = @c;
} else {
     @a = scalar @b;
}
```

While

```
@a = @b || @c;
```

<s>and also</s>

```
@a = @b // @c;
```

both mean

means

```
if (@b) {
     @a = scalar @b;
} else {
     @a = @c;
}
```

The only way to get rid of the `scalar` in assigning `@b` to `@a` is to use `?:`

```
@a = @b ? @b : @c;
```

which of course means

```
if (@b) {
    @a = @b;
} else {
    @a = @c;
}
```

There is also the property that `?:` can be an lvalue:

```
(@a > @b ? @a : @b) = @c;
```

which of course means

```
if (@a > @b) {
    @a = @c;
} else {
    @b = @c;
}
```

---

## EDIT

The implementation of `@a // @b`  and its definition differ.  Bug submitted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.could you show how does this code work?`@a=@b//@c` it seems “//” is not the same as “||”,see:`perl -e '@arr1=();@arr2=(1,2,3);@arr3=@arr1//@arr2;print "[@arr3]\n"` and `perl -e '@arr1=();@arr2=(1,2,3);@arr3=@arr1||@arr2;print "[@arr3]\n"`

Comment: Calling defined on an array is itself undefined. Gosh, you’er right that there is something screwy here. Amongst other things, it matters whether it is a global or not whether `defined(@arry)` warns you.

Comment: look at this, still weird! <pre> <code>perl -e '@arr1=();@arr2=(1,2,3);if(@arr1){@arr3=scalar @arr1}else{@arr3=@arr2};print "[@arr3]\n"'
[1 2 3]

perl -e '@arr1=();@arr2=(1,2,3);@arr3=@arr1//@arr2;print "[@arr3]\n"'
[0]</code>

Comment: @ss-perl: I’ve now decided that you have discovered a legitimate bug in the way the `//` operator was defined and implemented.

Answer (score 10):

This has more to do with `defined` than with `//`. From [`perldoc -f defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html):

> **Use of `defined` on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is deprecated.** It used to report whether memory for that aggregate had ever been allocated. This behavior may disappear in future versions of Perl.

So in your first example, `defined(@arr1)` is false; in the second, `defined(@arr1)` is true, and `@arr3` contains `scalar(@arr1)`. The difference between `//` and `defined($a) ? $a : $b` is noted in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Defined-Or):

> Although it has no direct equivalent in C, Perl's `//` operator is related to its C-style `or`. In fact, it's exactly the same as `||`, except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its truth. Thus, `$a // $b` is similar to `defined($a) || $b` (except that it returns the value of `$a` rather than the value of `defined($a)`) and yields the same result as `defined($a) ? $a : $b` (except that **the ternary-operator form can be used as a lvalue, while `$a // $b` cannot**). This is very useful for providing default values for variables. If you actually want to test if at least one of `$a` and `$b` is defined, use `defined($a // $b)`.

(Emphasis mine.)

So for example:

```
(defined($a) ? $a : $b) = $c;    # This is valid.
($a // $b) = $c;                 # This is not.
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! yes, I notice this on perlop before, but still feel confused, could you explan it more, since I'm a new perl learner, thanks again!!

Comment: I'm not sure that it does apply, because the forms are being used on the right side of the assignment, not as lvalues.